# Ignoring a "Property type is incompatible with type inherited from" warning in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, warnings, clang, suppress-warnings

In a subclass, I'm overriding the type of a property to be a subclass of that property, which works like this:

```
ClassA: NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSValue *value;

ClassB : ClassA
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *value;
```

However, I found that if `ClassA` didn't `#import` the `NSNumber` class, then `ClassB` would have a warning in the form of: `Property type 'NSNumber *' is incompatible with type 'NSValue *' inherited from 'ClassA'`.

I don't want to have a bunch of unnecessary imports in `ClassA`. How can I override the warning from Clang about this? I know the syntax is:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-somethingGoesHere"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

But I don't know what flag I should pass. Is there a place I can look up what flag to pass for that warning? I referenced the [Clang User manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) and tried to disable all warnings for just that line using the `"-w"` flag, but that didn't work.

Comment: I learned that the `-fdiagnostics-show-option` can be passed to Clang to show the associated warning group for the warning (which you can use to suppress that warning group). I'm not sure how to view that in Xcode, so I compiled on the command line. Unfortunately, while I got warning groups for retain cycles and such, none was printed for this specific warning, so there may not be a specific flag.

Answer (score 2):

You could reveal the warning in the Xcode build log activities and find the clang flag. Try this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wincompatible-property-type"
...
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: For further reference: https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/tools/clang/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html

Answer (score 1):

i was facing a problem slightly similar to your problem
hope this answer will work for you also.
 [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859596/ignore-clang-warnings-related-to-property).

and Now i got the solution to ignore warnings. hope this solution will help to u also.

Answer (score -2):

You should not override properties in subclasses. I understand why you think you should, but it's really not the right design. Name the second one something else, like "numberValue".

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Subclasses specialize in some way relative to their superclass, i.e. a `UITableViewCell` subclass might specify that it's `backgroundView` property is a `UIImageView` so that it can draw an image as the background. Moreover, there is no warning for it when the classes are #imported in the header, indicating that there is no problem with it.

Comment: The reason it's bad is because the code in B will always assume that value is an NSNumber, while code in A may set value to an NSValue. This can lead to runtime exceptions in B because you have lost compile-time type checking. At that point you might as well just use an "id" for value.