# Ignore clang warnings related to property

Tags: ios, clang, compiler-warnings

i want to ignore these warnings these warning appeared when i used 
**valid architechtures : arm64 armv7 armv7s**

[image: warning screenshot]

[image: warning screenshot2]

these type of warnings appearing in many headers .

i want to ignore these warnings just like clang does for deprecated warnings.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
```

i want something like this or any compiler flags to ignore these warnings

[image: warnings screenshot3]

Comment: You most certainly don't want to ignore those as not fixing them renders a broken app. An `NSString` should be (copy), just like all  mutable collections.

Comment: what about that property of uiviewcontroller.

Comment: i am using black raccoon(https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon) as library project in my myproject , and it has more than 100 warnings like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the log navigator (the last tab on the left panel in Xcode), you can expand the "transcripts" (see [View and filter logs and reports](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev21d56ecd4)). Once you find the one that shows the build warnings, you can see what the precise `-W` code for each is, and then suppress it via your `#pragma`.

Thus, in your revised question, you show us the `-W` code in question is `-Wobjc-property-no-attribute`. Thus you could do:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-property-no-attribute"
...
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: i had open transcripts i can see [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute] this thing how to suppress it ??

Comment: oh you mean to clang it ,#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-property-no-attribute" ,, thanks i m trying it