# Xcode- C programming - While loop

Tags: c, xcode, while-loop

I have an error/warning associated with "while" loop, in Xcode. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
while ( (c=getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);
```

> While loop has empty body

Picture in the IDE:

[image: C programming using Xcode]

Comment: Please don't post images of code, post code.

Comment: do you know copy/paste _as text_ ?

Comment: this warning is stupid. The loop has a side effect.

Comment: here: I manually OCR'ed that for you

Comment: you could add a body: move `c!=EOF` in it.

Comment: I try to put the semicolon for empty code blocks on a separate line to make it obvious that it's intentional. Probably won't do anything for the warning message though.

Comment: I'm at work, without access to Xcode. Somebody should check whether 'Empty loop bodies' is still one of the warnings one can enable or disable in the project build settings. If so, that's the answer.

Comment: @Tommy, however this feature is useful for things like `while (i < 0);`

Comment: Lol. The warning isn’t “stupid” and the side effect may well be intended (to skip to the end of the line). The intent of the warning is that, in C, where braces are optional, it’s easy to accidentally include the semicolon when it wasn’t intended. The solution is to make the intent explicit, e.g. `while (...) { }` (with nothing in the braces) instead of `while (...);`.

Comment: @Rob there's a way to turn it off with clang for that particular occurrence, see my answer. Yes, looks very much like your comment, now I notice.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah, my first step in starting a new Xcode-or-anything project is to turn every available warning on. Unrelated comment: having edited the image out of the post, it's no longer clear that the author is actually referring to a warning, not an error. Do you think it's justified also to tweak the text?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Yes, I know how to turn off warnings. By the way, you can do that either as a clang command line switch or with a `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-W..."` as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23859952/1271826). Or there's actually an "empty loop bodies" setting in your target build options (you have to show all settings to see it). But, like you, I think it best to just write code to make this explicit (using `{ }` or, at least with `;` on its own line) and not suppress the warning at all. It's a useful warning for Objective-C programming.

Comment: not saying you don't know. and turning them off is indeed a bad idea. Better to change locally so the warning doesn't appear.

Comment: @Rob that said, I downloaded clang for windows and I can't get this empty body warning even with `-Wempty-body`. Windows version outdated?

Comment: I downloaded Windows clang (`clang --version` reports 5.0.0) and `clang test.c` reported empty body (as did `clang -Wempty-body test.c`). Only when I did `clang -Wno-empty-body test.c` did I not see empty body warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing which compiler is behind it, I can just list the know warning flags for 2 of them:

- **clang** `-Wempty-body`; included in `-Wextra` too;
- **Visual C++** [C4390](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534523/does-while1-do-the-same-as-while1), included in `/W3`

(source: [Why didn't the compiler warn me about an empty if-statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482904/why-didnt-the-compiler-warn-me-about-an-empty-if-statement))

While this compiler warning is very useful for conditions without side-effects like

```
while (i > 0);
{
   --i;
}
```

(which would cause an infinite loop)

in your specific case:

```
while ( (c=getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);
```

is a perfectly idiomatic way of skipping to the next line of `stdin` or end of input.

From the text of the warning that XCode prints (and which comes from the underlying compiler), I'm pretty sure that your XCode is configured with `clang`, so, yes, there's a way to turn the warning off when using `clang`:

```
$ clang test.c 
test.c:6:12: warning: while loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
  while (0);
           ^
test.c:6:12: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
```

in your case:

```
while ( (c=getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF)
;
```

in that case (matter of personal taste) I would do:

```
while ( (c=getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF)
{}
```

since they are [strictly equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534523/does-while1-do-the-same-as-while1)

So you can leave the warning set for other cases where a semicolon could be typed unwillingly and explicitly tell the compiler not to worry about those cases.

Comment: Thank you! Semicolon on the next line did silence the warning!