# why clang -Wempty-body doesn't detect this case?

Tags: c, clang, compiler-warnings

After answering [Xcode- C programming - While loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496135/xcode-c-programming-while-loop), I stopped making theoric answers and installed `clang` on my Windows box to check if it's really better than `gcc` in the warning diagnostics department.

I'm using `-Wempty-body` in `clang` to compile this code, which is wrong because:

- the while instruction ends with a semicolon, possible typo after long hours ending lines with semicolons...: infinite loop
- same thing for `if` statement, making the test useless

wrong code:

```
int main(void)
{
   char c=1;
   while (c);
   --c;
   if (c);
}
```

I tried to compile it with `clang` (5.0.0 x64 windows):

output:

```
S:\c>clang -Wempty-body test.c
test.c:8:10: warning: if statement has empty body [-Wempty-body]
   if (c);
         ^
```

So empty `if` is detected while `while` isn't.

Now I'm wrapping the decrement instruction in a block after the `while`:

```
int main(void)
{
   char c=1;
   while (c);
   { --c; }
   if (c);
}
```

now it seems to detect both properly:

```
test.c:6:10: warning: if statement has empty body [-Wempty-body]
   if (c);
test.c:4:13: warning: while loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
   while (c);
```

note: `gcc` wasn't able to see either `while` bug, so `clang` is still clearly superior in terms of warning detection (see also [why am I not getting an "used uninitialized" warning from gcc in this trivial example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465442/why-am-i-not-getting-an-used-uninitialized-warning-from-gcc-in-this-trivial-ex))

What's the heuristics behind this? Is that a bug?

Comment: Is not the bug. While(C); is in the common use and it waits C to clear

Comment: @PeterJ_01 the `c` needs not be re-evaluated here, it is a local variable without pointers to it.

Comment: JFF you may have figured out an edge-case that clang doesn't take care of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to avoid too many false positives. In general, `if (expr);` never makes sense, but `while (expr);` need not be an error, because `expr`'s side effects could cause the expression to switch from true to false. For instance,

```
void processAllElements() {
  while (tryProcessNextElement());
}
```

Here's how [the source](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/a38ba9770a70056f9fdd6c71f819e5db45a105e4/lib/Sema/SemaChecking.cpp) explains it:

```
// `for(...);' and `while(...);' are popular idioms, so in order to keep
// noise level low, emit diagnostics only if for/while is followed by a
// CompoundStmt, e.g.:
//    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++);
//    {
//      a(i);
//    }
// or if for/while is followed by a statement with more indentation
// than for/while itself:
//    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++);
//      a(i);
```

Comment: exactly what I wrote in may comment. while (); is in too common use to warn every time.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Not exactly the same as what you wrote. In fact, I disagree with what you wrote for the same reason that Antti Haapala did.

Comment: C means any statement  - by coincidence OP used this letter for the variable name. Very narrow tunnel vision :)